# Linux resume when using multiple swap partitions

Tags: linux-kernel, swap, power-management

If a Linux system is using more than one swap device and suspend to disk, how does one setup the `resume=` kernel parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible.

The [Software Suspend documentation says](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt?h=v4.17#n327):

> ```
> Q: Does swsusp (to disk) use only one swap partition or can it use
> multiple swap partitions (aggregate them into one logical space)?
>
> A: Only one swap partition, sorry.
> ```

Thanks to [Flow's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451943/143394) for the link.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. You can use suspend-to-disk even if you have multiple swap partitions. But the 'resume=` kernel parameter only takes exactly one partition, which is used for suspend to disk.

Comment: @Flow Are you sure? Have you tried it or seen it?  What if the one named swap partition happens to not have enough space?

If it was you who down-voted, I welcome constructive criticism.

Comment: "What if the one named swap partition happens to not have enough space?" Then hibernation fails. But that isn't a matter of having one or multiple swap partitions.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for you assertion that it works with multiple partitions?
I forgot to reference you by the way - added now.

Answer (score 2):

Just like if you only have one swap device, i.e., specify exactly one partition as value of `resume=`. The Kernel Documentation on the `resume` kernel command-line parameter make it clear that it only takes one device.

```
resume=       [SWSUSP]          
              Specify the partition device for software suspend
              Format:
              {/dev/<dev> | PARTUUID=<uuid> | <int>:<int> | <hex>}
```

<sup>Source https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt?h=v4.17#n3767</sup>

More information about suspend-to-swap can be found at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt?h=v4.17

Comment: So if I only specify one of the n devices, will it work it out?

Comment: Yes, the device given to 'resume=' will be used to when writing the data from RAM to disk, and on resumption, to search for the data to be written back from disk to RAM. It hasn't even be of the size of your physical RAM, hibernation may even work in this case, but if you wan't to make sure, make it the size of the RAM.

Comment: [My answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452385/143394) seems to say it's impossible. Do you have a counter-reference?

Comment: Your quote appears to state exactly what I wrote: You can only use exactly one swap partition for suspend to disk.